# Why can't I configure the perspective camera to have the actual sizes in three js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js

I am using Three Js for visualizing a car, but I am having a problem with my perspective camera

[image]

I would like it to look more real: I want to see only the front, not the back. I'm clear? haha

I have tried to change a lot of [properties](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/cameras/PerspectiveCamera), but I am not being able to do it.

Here is the [github repository](https://github.com/MartinSobel/Seltos3D).

Comment: Have you tried to change the field of view range on your perspective camera? `cameraPano = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 11000 )`

Comment: @jscastro yes, I tried, but it only makes a zoom off

Comment: You can't expect others to go digging through your repository to find the necessary code. Please include the relevant code in the question itself. See here for how to ask a helpful question with a minimal example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: looks like your field of view is too small or the car is far from the camera. Note that if you want help with code you're require to put a minimal repo in the question itself. Linking to your github repo is off topic for stack overflow. You shouldn't need your car model to repo the issue. A simple box will produce the same results and we can see what you're doing, especially if you use a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see in your code you are changing the FOV with the mouse wheel...
Is this what you want to do?
I would expect you would change the camera z position to zoom in and out, not the FOV.

I suggest you do like what jscastro says in the comments and make yout camera fov 45 and move your camera closer and **make your scroll event change the camera position, not the fov**.

Here is a demo where you can change the camera fov and z position to see how they interact.

```js
var camera, scene, renderer, mesh, material, stats;
init();
animate();

function init() {
    // Renderer.
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    //renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    // Add renderer to page
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    // Create camera.
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
    camera.position.z = 400;

    // Create scene.
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // Create material
    material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();

    // Create cube and add to scene.
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(200, 200, 200);
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(mesh);

    // Create ambient light and add to scene.
    var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040); // soft white light
    scene.add(light);

    // Create directional light and add to scene.
    var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    directionalLight.position.set(1, 1, 1);
    scene.add(directionalLight);

    // Add listener for window resize.
    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
    
    // Add dat.gui.
    var gui = new dat.GUI();
    var fovgui = gui.add(camera, "fov").onChange(function(newvalue){
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }).name('camera.fov');
    var posgui = gui.add(camera.position, "z").name('camera.position.z');
    
    gui.add({click: function(){
      camera.fov = 5;
      camera.position.z = 5000;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      fovgui.updateDisplay();
      posgui.updateDisplay();
    }}, 'click').name('FOV:5 Z:5000');
    
    gui.add({click: function(){
      camera.fov = 70;
      camera.position.z = 400;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      fovgui.updateDisplay();
      posgui.updateDisplay();
    }}, 'click').name('FOV:70 Z:400');
    
    gui.add({click: function(){
      camera.fov = 130;
      camera.position.z = 190;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      fovgui.updateDisplay();
      posgui.updateDisplay();
    }}, 'click').name('FOV:130 Z:190');

}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    mesh.rotation.x += 0.005;
    mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}
```

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/dataarts/dat.gui/master/build/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/dataarts/dat.gui/master/build/dat.gui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.min.js"></script>
```